# Задача по JavaScript с DOM элементами?

Tags: javascript, dom

помогите решить простую задачу, я вроде и сам решил но не понимаю что не правильно)

Выберите 3 DOM элемента:

- обратитесь к элементу div> по id = "test" и присвойте выбранный элемент переменной id.
- обратитесь к элементу div> по классу class = "test" и присвойте выбранные элементы переменной className
- обратитесь к элементу div> по тегу и присвойте выбранные элементы переменной tag

я написал так:

```js
var id=document.getElementById("test");
var className = document.getElementByClassName("test");
var tag = document.getElementByTagName("div")
```

но все ровно что-то не так.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что что-то не так?

Answer (score 2):

Множественное число -  *document.getElement**s**By...Name*

```js
var id = document.getElementById("test");
var className = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
console.log(id);
console.log(className);
console.log(tag);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div class="test" id="one"></div>
<div class="test" id="two"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло то, что добавилось вывод в консоль для каждого элемента)

Comment: @AlexKushnir Пожалуйста. Успехов! Значок "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Также, есть вероятность, что вам необходимо использовать селекторы и методы `querySelector` и `querySelectorAll`.

Тогда, соответственно, код будет выглядеть вот так:

```js
var id = document.querySelector("#test");
var className = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
var tag = document.querySelectorAll("div");
console.log(id);
console.log(className);
console.log(tag);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div class="test" id="one"></div>
<div class="test" id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для выбора элементов по id можно использовать метод `getElementById` - так как id - это уникальный идентификатор, на странице может существовать только один элемент с таким id и этот метод возвращает один единственный элемент. Метод называется соответствующе.

Для выбора элементов, например, по имени класса - можно использовать метод `getElementsByClassName`, так как одинаковых классов на странице может быть очень много - метод называется getElementS.. и возвращает, условно, массив всех элементов, которые попадают под этот классовый селектор.

У вас просто метод выбора по классу не правильно называется.

Comment: а давайте снова похоливарим, пруф на то, что `id` уникален _на всей странице_ - в студию :)

Comment: @teran никто не мешает влупить хоть пару десятков элементов с одинаковым идентификатором) только вот никто не гарантирует одинакового поведения в разных браузерах при работе с этими элементами, думаю, что и сам понимаешь это :) \n в хроме селектор по этому айди отдаст последний элемент в доме, в фаерфоксе другое поведение вроде, в сафари и того хуже дела обстоят. \n Ну а вообще, мне кажется, никаких пруфов и давать не нужно, потому что используя не уникальные идентификаторы разработчик сам себе копает яму, куда потом баги ссыпать будут.

Comment: дак может использовать просто с головой надо? а не абы-как? В стандарте описано было вроде что getElementById должен вернуть первый элемент. А что касается уникальности на странице, то опять таки, как тут уже не раз спорили, уникальность требуется в поддереве, а не всем документе.

Comment: @teran "с головой" дублировать идентификаторы?) Естественно, все надо делать "с головой", тут не поспоришь.

Comment: @teran https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp цитирую "The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).", подчёркиваю "must be unique within the HTML document". Или я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: вы [стандарт откройте](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-id-attribute), а не w3schools.

Comment: @teran верно, в спецификации сказано "The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s home subtree" 
home subtree - это же html element в большинстве случаев? Разве может быть несколько home subtree?

Comment: ну там же есть определение `home subtree`, - это дерево с вершиной в непосредственно родительском элементе данного узла. Так что на странице может быть несколько элементов с одинаковыми ID, таких что их home-substree не пересекаются никак.

Comment: Например, в таблице `id` для `td`. Home-subtree это `tr` со всем в нее вложенным. Разные строки не имеют пересечений, так что давать одинаковые id в разных строках - вполне законно, и в целом даже удобно, когда строки обрабатываются последовательно, и нужно достать информацию с какой то конкретной ячейки. Доступ по классу вернет массив, а по ID сразу один нужный элемент. Так что ID в данной задаче предпочтительнее.

Comment: @teran как доступ по одинаковому айди вернёт сразу один нужный элемент? Или перебирать строки и там выбирать нужную ячейку, тогда как ее выбирать из строки?

Comment: @teran и как насчёт того, что валидатор w3c ругается на дублирование айди на одной странице?

Comment: валидатор может чутка устареть. Раньше в стандарте писалось про уникальность во всем документе. про home subtree появилось вроде только  в 5й версии. В предыдущих обсуждениях (если поискать) сравнивали определения.